Workbook tab Color count loop
I need help with a loop to count all colored tabs in a workbook.  I have 4 different colors, I would like to data to sum on the first tab of the workbook showing how many green, yellow...ect.
Public Sub

For Each mysheet in ActiveWorkbook.sheets
     If mysheet.tab.color = RGB(255,0,0) then
      mysheet.tab.count 
     End If
  Next mysheet
End Sub

This code was an experiment using code from another Macro, this is not a functioning code.  I was thinking about a do while loop with counter?
NEW CODE:
Public Sub TabCount()
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, i As Long, O As Long
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
i = 0
O = 0
For Each mysheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
          x = x + 1
ElseIf mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
          y = y + 1
ElseIf mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) Then
          z = z + 1
ElseIf mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
         i = i + 1
ElseIf mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then
         O = O + 1
  End If
 
Next mysheet

'Need help here with pasting data.
End Sub


you will need a variable for each count and use else elseif to change by color.

If the # of colors were unknown, this would be a good use case for a Scripting.Dictionary. Otherwise, just use 4 variables.

@BigBen I still think this would be a good use case. I imagine the ultimate delivery would be to count each of the colors and report the total count for each, and not bind it to a specific color, but instead see what colors are used and count each and show. However, that may be a personal shortcoming because I don't have much exposure to the scripting.dictionary

List Tab Colors Count

Best tested in a copy of your workbook before getting familiar with it. It will write to the first (left-most) worksheet. Rather use the name (e.g. "Sheet1") instead of the index (1) when referencing it (dws).


Sub ListTabColors()

    Dim Headers() As Variant:
    Headers = VBA.Array("ID", "ColorNum", "Color", "Count")

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(1) ' improve!
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim ssh As Object, Color As Long
    
    For Each ssh In wb.Sheets
        Color = ssh.Tab.Color
        dict(Color) = dict(Color) + 1
    Next ssh
            
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict.Count + 1
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(Headers) + 1
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A2").Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    Dim r As Long: r = 1
    
    dws.UsedRange.Clear
    
    Dim Key As Variant, c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To dcCount
        Data(1, c) = Headers(c - 1)
    Next c
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        r = r + 1
        Data(r, 1) = r - 1
        Data(r, 2) = Key
        drg.Cells(r, 3).Interior.Color = Key
        Data(r, 4) = dict(Key)
    Next Key
    
    With drg
        .Value = Data
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
     
    With dws.Range("A1")
        .Value = "Tab Colors"
        With .Font
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 14
        End With
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Tab colors count listed.", vbInformation
     
End Sub


This is the more dynamic solution, but for a novice user could be cryptic. A note before a given sub-section explaining what it's accomplishing would probably go a long way if it needed to be adjusted or re-purposed. This is awesome though.

If you start this code on a sheet which contains something delete the sheet content without any warning. I think this is not a user friendly solution.

You need to use a variable that is set to 0 outside of your loop. Then instead of just counting the tab (which will always result in 1 or 0, as you wrote it) you need to then add 1 to the variable. Then as it iterates through all your sheets it will have changed the variable to the count of the sheets that trigger TRUE for your IF condition.
So to clarify, first you say x = 0, then you start iterating through your sheets and everytime it sees a tab with that color it will redefine x as x + 1, otherwise it will remain the previous value. Then after going through it will have effectively counted all the tabs that color and give you the count in the immediate window of the VBA window. You can change it to a messagebox or cell value.
Dim x as Long
x = 0
For Each mysheet in ActiveWorkbook.sheets
     If mysheet.tab.color = RGB(255,0,0) then
        x = x + 1 
     End If
Next mysheet

Debug.Print x

End Sub

If you need to do this for more than one color, you can add a new block using a new variable, or even the same variable as long as you reset the value back to 0 and print the previous count somewhere (otherwise you wouldn't know the count).
Dim x as Long, y as long, z as long

x = 0
For Each mysheet in ActiveWorkbook.sheets
     If mysheet.tab.color = RGB(255,0,0) then
        x = x + 1 
     End If
Next mysheet

y = 0
For Each mysheet in ActiveWorkbook.sheets
     If mysheet.tab.color = RGB(255,255,0) then
        y = y + 1 
     End If
Next mysheet

Debug.Print x

End Sub

Alternatively, you can create an ELSEIF condition to handle it in a single logic, this is what I'd recommend if you know what your colors will be and they won't be changing, otherwise you may need to edit this, in that case it may be worthwhile to create a variable for the different colors in one spot so you can easily maintain it or have it reference somewhere so it's further automated:
Dim x as Long, y as long, z as long

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
For Each mysheet in ActiveWorkbook.sheets
     If mysheet.tab.color = RGB(255,0,0) then
             x = x + 1 
         ElseIf mysheet.tab.color = RGB(255,255,0) then
             y = y + 1
         ElseIf mysheet.tab.color = RGB(0,255,0) then
             z = z + 1
     End If
Next mysheet

'Print x, y, & z somewhere for results

End Sub


Public Sub TabCount()
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim O As Long
Dim P As Long
x = 0
i = 0
O = 0
P = 0
For Each mysheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
x = x + 1
End If
If mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
i = i + 1
End If
If mysheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
O = O + 1
End If
Next mysheet
Debug.Print x 'This would paste into Cells here?
Debug.Print i
Debug.Print O
Debug.Print P
End Sub
'just need end paste.

@SkyeOlsavsky I'm not sure what you're asking here as the formatting got a bit lost. Are you trying to figure how to accomplish this for more than one color at once?

@SkyeOlsavsky figuring that's what you wanted I modified the code to show 2 ways that you could scale it. I'd recommend the ElseIf approach if you have a limited, fixed amount of colors the tabs could be.

Correct, I have colors green, yellow, orange, red, and blue. So 5 colors, I apologize for that misinformation.  I would like the Code to count each color and retain that data to then paste into The first Tab "REF" in 4 different Cells.  So the grouped logic would not be what I want. I would have to separate this with Blocks, (shown above)   Thank you, I am learning very much the more I ask. I will try the separated blocks and see.

@SkyeOlsavsky Try the ElseIf method, change the codes and add more variables as needed but that should show you the general setup, just need more ElseIf's. Then in the Ref. just assign a few cells with the value and a label beside it so you know which is which. The elseif method should be a bit quicker as it runs through the tabs once, whereas separate blocks will run through it each time.

Just having trouble with calling what "Object" to paste the counted values. @Mark S. you mentioned assigning the cells something in my ref page? Would I have the Cells equal the variable?  I am probably overthinking this.

Yes exactly, it'd look something like Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).value = x then the next being Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,1).value = y Assuming you want the numbers in column one. Similarly, you can have the color ID drop there and put the values in the column over by changing the second value to 2, so it shows the color code and then the count beside it.

Mark, Thank you very much for helping/educating me on this. I will assign the paste for each variable.

The answer you chose should address all that though, this is just how to modify what I have here.

I am running the macro, it appears to only be working for Colors: yellow and red.
I did double check the RGB codes to make sure the color was matching. EX RGB(0,255,0).
Green (which is the first color, (variable X) will not populate and the first 20 tabs are green.

So use a macro recorder to get the code for green

Sheet Tab color can have a numeric value referencing to the actual color of the tab, or a boolean which indicates that the colorindex is set to xlColorIndexNone
Sub tab_color()

For each ws in Worksheets

if TypeName(ws.Tab.Color) = "Boolean" then
  nocolor=nocolor+1
end if

next ws

Msgbox "Count of no colored tabs: " & nocolor

End Sub


This is an excel strangeness. Good to know
